# C# Weather program, how to retrieve specific values from loop

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, for-loop, weather

I'm creating a weather program with random heat from -10 to 50 °C. i have it working but i need to find the specific days there was frost(under 0; -1, -5, etc...). i have a counter for how many frost days there are but i can't seem to find out how to get those specific days and print them on the screen. here's my code:

```
Random x = new Random();
int day = 1;
int frostDays = 0;
double sum = 0;
int[] days = {5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100};

int[] heat = new int[100];

for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
{
    heat[0] = x.Next(-10, 51);

    if (heat[0] < 0)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine("Day number " + day + " heat " + heat[0]);
        frostDays++;
    }
    Console.Write(heat[0] + " ** ");
    if (days.Contains(day))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
    //Console.WriteLine("Heat day " + day + ". is: " + heat[0]);

    sum += heat[0];
    day++;
}

double average = sum / 100;

Console.WriteLine("Heat sum: " + sum);
Console.WriteLine("average heat: " + average.ToString("F2") + " °C");
Console.WriteLine("frost days: " + frostDays);
```

OUTPUT: http://oi57.tinypic.com/mw4myv.jpg

I'm trying to retrieve the specific days(day numbers) which are frost(under 0°C) with their heat and print it on the screen, i can't seem to find out how, if anyone can help, please answer, greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include the output *as text*. You've got a text-based program - there's no reason to have an image for the output.

Comment: Also, what is your `heat` array meant to represent? You're only ever using `heat[0]`, which doesn't seem right to me...

Comment: the heat array is meant to represent the heat of that specific day.

Comment: Okay - well you'll need to use more than one element then, won't you? And what's the `days` array meant to represent? (I'm trying to help you learn how to think about your own code, rather than just giving an answer.)

Comment: days is kind of irrelevant, just used it in an if statement to put the heat in a smaller format

Comment: So it's just meant to be something to add a line break every fifth day? Just use `if (day % 5 == 4)` instead. (It's worth thinking about the *names* of your variables - even if you *did* want to use an array, something like `daysToAddLineBreak` or something would be clearer than `days`.)

Comment: i translated the variables for the question, it's in another language. and thanks for the answer on the line brake but do you know how i can get the specific frost days displayed?

Comment: ther is a start date? the day are consecutive?

Comment: @Realitiez: Well you've so far ignored my point that you're currently only using `heat[0]`. You're not actually populating the array. I suspect you want `heat[day]` instead. Then you can go over the array afterwards to find out which days were frosty - currently you're not actually storing that information.

Comment: if i change the heat[0 to heat[day] i get 0's for heat values and an error after execution.

Comment: there is a start date? the day are consecutive?

Comment: the start date is just day 1. yes, consecutive days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you change your structure to a more object oriented approach.

You should create a `Day` object, which will contain:

- The Day's Temperature
- If the Day had frost

This can be represented in a small class:

```
public class Day
{
    public int Temperature { get; set; }
    public bool Frost { get { return Temperature < 0; } }

    public Day(int temperature)
    {
        Temperature = temperature;
    }
}
```

Now that you have something to *store* your data in, you need to work on the logic of the program. (Which no offense, is not very well structured)

Start off by giving your program a few variables:

```
private const totalDays = 100; //Replace your hardcoded "100"s with this
private const int minTemp = -10; //Pretty self explanitory, the min and max temperatures for a day to generate
private const int maxTemp = 50;
```

Because your question states you are looking for frost days, I am going to modify your logic to only print them. Also note that you are incorrectly accessing your arrays by using `heat[0]`, that will always get the first element at the `0` position, when you should be using `heat[i]` to get the value at the `i`th position.

The code should be as follows:

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalDays; i++)
{
    days[i] = new Day(x.Next(minTemp, maxTemp + 1)); //Create a day with random temperature
    if (days[i].Frost) //The "Frost" propery returns true if the "Temperature" is below 0
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Day {0} is frosty!", i);
    }
}
```

Notice how I modified your for loop to start at `0`, rather than `1`, as this is the start of the array. I also changed `x.Next` to take the new `minTemp` and `maxTemp` values into account.

---

If you want to get and process just the frost items, you can simply loop through them and check if a `Day`s `Frost` property is true.

So to recap, your code should look like this:

```
class Program
{
    private const int totalDays = 100;
    private const int minTemp = -10;
    private const int maxTemp = 50;
    private static Day[] days = new Day[totalDays];
    private static Random x = new Random();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < totalDays; i++)
        {
            days[i] = new Day(x.Next(minTemp, maxTemp + 1)); //Create a day with random temperature
            sum += days[i].Temperature;
            Console.WriteLine("Day {0} is {1} degrees and is{2} frosty", i, days[i].Temperature, days[i].Frost ? string.Empty : " not");
        }

        double average = sum / totalDays;

        Console.WriteLine("Total Temperature: {0} °C", sum);
        Console.WriteLine("Average Temperature {0} °C", average.ToString("F2"));

        for (int i = 0; i < totalDays; i++)
        {
            if (days[i].Frost)
            {
                //Do something
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public class Day
{
    public int Temperature { get; set; }
    public bool Frost { get { return Temperature < 0; } }

    public Day(int temperature)
    {
        Temperature = temperature;
    }
}
```